# How to remove first 'n' characters from file names in one command

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I saw several posting how to remove parts from file names but for different scenarios as mine.

I want to remove 'n' characters from files in a folder in command.
From

```
Song-01-Artist-JohnDoe - songtitle-A.mp3
Song-01-Artist-JohnDoe - songtitle-B.mp3
Song-01-Artist-JohnDoe - songtitle-C.mp3
```

changed to

```
songtitle-A.mp3
songtitle-B.mp3
songtitle-C.mp3
```

How can I accomplish that?
Any help is much appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Probably easier ways to do this (`rename` in one of its incarnations comes to mind) but a simplistic loop might be `for name in *; do mv "$name" "${name:25}"; done`.  Be careful with whitespace in the file names.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Perl-based `rename` command, either with a sed-like regular expression substitution

```
rename -n 's/.{25}//' -- *.mp3
```

or with a simple substring operation

```
rename -n '$_ = substr($_,25)' -- *.mp3
```

or switching to `zsh` and making use of the same kind of string slicing as suggested in [u/doneal24's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492128/how-to-remove-first-n-characters-from-file-names-in-one-command#comment2614002_1492128)

```
autoload -Uz zmv        # best put in your .zshrc

zmv -n '(*.mp3)' '${1:25}'
```

*In all cases, remove the `-n` once you are happy with the proposed actions.*